# Let $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)..(x+100)$ and $g(x)=f(x)f’’(x)-(f’(x))^2$. Find number of roots $n$ of $g(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

After relevant simplification ie. Log on both sides and then differentiating, the expression received is
$$\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)} =\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x+k}$$

Differentiating again will give
$$\frac{g(x)}{(f(x))^2}=-\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{(x+k)^2}$$

So in turn, the roots of $g(x)=0$ are simply the roots of $f(x)=0$, so ans should be 100, but that’s not correct.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $\log(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$ . So how can you take log?

Comment: Vivaan, the result can be derived in the same way without the use of Log. Its just the product rule for derivatives.

Comment: @VivaanDaga I did it because it was an SOP. I didn’t check about it’s validity

Comment: @RenanWillianPrado Division by $0$ is still happening (though it can be fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)} =\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{x+k}$$
D.w.r.t. $x$ both sides
$$\frac{f(x)f''(x)-f'^2(x)}{f^2(x)}=-\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{(x+k)^2}<0 \ne 0.$$
So $$g(x)=f(x)f''(x)-f'^2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f^2(x)}{(x+k)^2}$$
Then $$-g(x)=(x+2)^2(x+3)^2(x+4)^2....(x+n)^2+ (x+1)^2(x+3)^2(x+4)^2....(x+n)^2+......>0 \ne 0,$$ has no real root.

Comment: Won’t the $f^2(x)$ go to RHS?

Comment: You may see my edited answer.